# Fresnel - Kirchoff integral in paraxial approximation

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'd like to integrate this equation numerically.

```
b = 62.5*10^-6;
a = 4*10^-6;
n_co = 1.473;
n_cl = n_co - 0.016;
n_s  = 1.37868*10^-5;
L = 457.9*10^-9;
k = 2*%pi/L;
z = 0.4 ;
x =0.3;

int(exp(-1i*(2*k*(n_cl-n_s)*(sqrt(b^2 - x_p.^2))+2*k*(n_co-n_cl)*(sqrt(a^2-x_p.^2))))*exp(1i*((x-x_p).^2)/2*z),-a,a);
```

so what should i do to get result numerically. Since it contains exponential and complex functions hard to evaluate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate a function `f` in the interval `(from, to)` with `integral(f, from, to)`. For example, you can compute the value of the integral of exp(-x^2) from x=1 to 5 with:

```
f = @(x) exp(-x^2);
integral(f, 1, 5)
```